# Make Entity In Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony, makefile, doctrine, entity

I am trying to run in symfony 4.4

```
$ php bin/console make:entity
```

When I run it I get the error

```
In DoctrineHelper.php line 180:

Message: "Class "Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver" does not exist"
```

Other make: functions work ok. Does anyone know how to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't [installed](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) all the dependencies of doctrine. Run this command in the console.

```
composer require symfony/orm-pack
```